# how to change Background for all activities but does not change it in ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-theme

I need such ActionBar : [image: Correct ActionBarb but I have to write background for every activity manualy in layout!]

but I wish to have such background in `<style>` to use it for every activity automaticaly :

[image: Correct Background but problem with bg in text of ActionBar]

What should I change for I can use only background in `<style>` and do not apply background for every activity and don`t have any problems with Title of ActionBar ? 
When I comment`@color/bg_activity` in styles.xml I gets correct Bar (pic 1)

I use in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
<uses-sdk
    android:maxSdkVersion="22"
    android:minSdkVersion="13"
    android:targetSdkVersion="22" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AbnActionBarHolo" >
```

my `/res/values/styles.xml` :

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <!-- Base application theme. -->

    <!-- // AbnActionBarHolo // -->
    <style name="Theme.AbnActionBarHolo" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">

        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <!-- <item name="android:textColor">@color/foreground_text</item> -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/bg_activity</item>
        <!--  -->
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AbnActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/AbnActionBarTabText</item>
        <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="AbnActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">

        <!-- <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/MyActionBarTitleText</item> -->
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background_2</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background_2</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar title text -->
    <style name="AbnActionBarTitleText" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Holo.Widget.ActionBar.Title">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background_2</item>
        <item name="android:shadowColor">@color/actionbar_shadow_text</item>
    </style>

    <!-- ActionBar tabs text styles -->
    <style name="AbnActionBarTabText" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabText">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    </style>


</resources>
```

/res/values-v14/styles.xml

```
<resources>

    <!--
        Base application theme for API 14+. This theme completely replaces
        AppBaseTheme from BOTH res/values/styles.xml and
        res/values-v11/styles.xml on API 14+ devices.
    -->


    <!-- ActionBar styles -->
    <style name="AbnActionBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:titleTextStyle">@style/AbnActionBarTitleText</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_background_2</item>

        <!-- Support library compatibility -->
        <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_background_2</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

in `/res/values/colors.xml`

```
<resources>

    <!-- // ABN HOLO // -->
    <color name="actionbar_text">#FF000000</color>
    <color name="actionbar_shadow_text">#FFd3d3d3</color>

    <!--  -->
    <color name="black_overlay">#66000000</color>
    <color name="bg_activity">#ff000f2f</color>
    <color name="foreground_title">#ffff8800</color>
    <color name="foreground_version">#ffffa900</color>
    <color name="foreground_text">#FFFFFFFF</color>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating theme for actionbar create layout xml file (ex actionbar.xml) of your choice in layout folder and use that in every activity.

Example:
I have my actionbar.xml file in layout folder

```
      //----------ACTION BAR----------//
        ActionBar actionbar = getActionBar();


            TextView title;
                getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
                getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar); 
                title= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.title);
                title.setText("General Categories");
```

This is the best way of creating custom actionbar......

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android:windowBackground` instead of `android:background` when specifying the Activities' background.

```
<!-- // AbnActionBarHolo // -->
<style name="Theme.AbnActionBarHolo" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">

    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <!-- <item name="android:textColor">@color/foreground_text</item> -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/bg_activity</item>
    <!--  -->
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/AbnActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabTextStyle">@style/AbnActionBarTabText</item>
    <item name="android:actionMenuTextColor">@color/actionbar_text</item>
</style>
```